# How do I add a player to a local split screen game?

Tags: nintendo-switch, rico

On a Nintendo Switch, when you play Rico, how do you add the second player for a local coop game with split screen?
I am trying case mode, but can't find out how to add my friend. I don't have Nintendo online, and for local coop with split screen I should not need it.

Comment: Hey, welcome on Arqade SE. If you haven't already, you should take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if in need of guidance. I don't know this game, but usually, games don't allow multi-player in tutorials.

Comment: I can't add the second player in any mode. I bought the game only because it is supposed to be a couch coop game. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually I found out. Disconnect the second controller from the switch via the controller menu. Enter the game and go into the lobby. Reconnect the second controller. It will appear a player called player split screen.